# SVN to Mercurial conversion in windows

Tags: svn, mercurial

I am trying to convert a bunch of projects from SVN to Mercurial but I am having some trouble finding my way.  Everywhere I look for, it is said that I have to add the [Extensions] tag in .hgrc.  I have found a forum where someone says in Windows the line has to be added in the `mercurial.ini` file.  I've tried both (I can't even find the .ini file).

I am using Windows 7 64bits and Tortoise HG.

Any help?

Comment: Should be at `C:\Users\<username>\Mercurial.ini`

Comment: thanks, i found it around there in Appdata\Roaming\TortoiseHG
do u want to put it as an answer? so i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You should find the file at `C:\Users\<username>\Mercurial.ini`.

You can also poke around in `%AppData%` (type that in the Start Menu search bar).